# Rails3: combine scope with OR

Tags: ruby, activerecord, scope, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to combine name scope with or operator...
Something like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  scope :name_a, where("products.name = 'a'")
  scope :client_b, joins(:client).where("clients.name = 'b'")

  scope :name_a_or_b, name_a.or(client_b)  
end
```

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Arel documentation](http://github.com/rails/arel)

> The `OR` operator is not yet supported. It will work like this:
>   `users.where(users[:name].eq('bob').or(users[:age].lt(25)))`

[This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3Blockquote) shows you how to use the `.or` operator. However, it works with Arel objects while you have instances of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.
You can convert a relation to Arel using `Product.name_a.arel`, but now you have to figure out how to merge the conditions.

Answer (score 8):

Heres a hack I would use to deal with that missing feature:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  class << self
    def name_a
      where("products.name = 'a'")
    end

    def client_b
      joins(:client).where("clients.name = 'b'")
    end

    def name_a_or_b
      clauses = [name_a, client_b].map do |relation| 
        clause = relation.arel.where_clauses.map { |clause| "(#{clause})" }.join(' AND ')
        "(#{clause})" 
      end.join(' OR ')

      where clauses
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 3:

```
Person.where(
  Person.where(name: "John").where(lastname: "Smith").where_values.join(' OR ')
)
```