# Rails3 & ActiveRecord::Relation - Arel and OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel, active-relation

I have some scopes definied in a Model called Events. Now I need join them using OR operator. I’m using Rails3 and I’m a bit confused with ActiveRelation & Arel and how and how I should use this

```
scope :issues,   where(:subject_type =>  "Issue")
scope :for_company, lambda {|company| joins(:user)
                                      .where(:users => { :company_id => company.id })
                                      .includes(:user)}
```

How I can get events

```
for_company(x) OR issues
```

When I try `Events.for_company(X).or(issues)` I get an error

```
Events.for_company(Company.find(1)).or(Events.issues)
```

**NoMethodError: undefined method `or' for #ActiveRecord::Relation**

using `Events.for_company(Company.find(1)).arel.or(Events.issues)` I get

**NoMethodError: undefined method `or' for #Arel::SelectManager**

I want get all events that are issues or where user is from a determined company.

```
select * from events 
         join users  
           on events.user_id = users.id 
        where users.company_id = 1 
           or events.subject_type = "Issues"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you want to get as a result. One of your scopes is doing a join so you can't just add on another query which does no joins without doing a join on it as well or omitting joined columns.

Comment: First of all you in second scope you have joins and includes for users. It's not correct, just leave joins or includes (I think includes will only work with OR). There are no easy possibility to make OR for those two quiries, but you can do it using arel_table.

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby on Rails 3 howto make 'OR' condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291152/ruby-on-rails-3-howto-make-or-condition)
[Rails3: combine scope with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548548/rails3-combine-scope-with-or)

Answer (score -3):

```
Event.for_company(Company.find(1)).issues
```

Comment: Chaining scopes provides an `AND` operation