# Or & and in Rails ActiveRecord where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using Rails 3.2 and I've got a database table in which I want to find all the rows that match the following criteria:

a = true and b = true and ( 0< c <1 or d=1), a, b, c, d are columns.

Can I have something like:

```
 Route.where(:a => true,
             :b => true,
             :c => 0..1 OR :d=1
             ).all
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548548/rails3-combine-scope-with-or

Comment: Have a look on this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you could form that query using the Arel-based where function; you'd need to form up the database query string yourself.

Assuming you're using SQLite or Postgres:

```
Route.where("a = true and b = true and ((c > 0 and c < 1) or d = 1)").all
```

I haven't tested this code, but I suspect that might do the job for you. Note this is less 'portable' code; if you change the database you're using the query may break.

Comment: `where('a = :true and b = :true and ((c > :lo and c < :hi) or d = :d', :true => true, :lo => 0, :hi => 1, :d => 1)` would be safer, different databases uses different things for "true". Or even `.where(:a => true, :b => true).where('c > :lo and c < :hi) or d = :d', ...)`.

Answer (score 17):

In Rails 4 you can also do

`Route.where(:a => true,:b => true,:c => [1,2]).all`

This will find where c is 1 or 2.

Comment: Is .all is required ? I think it is default.

Comment: Yea .all isn't required, I was just keeping it consistent with the question.

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks. You can also use symbols like this: `Route.where(a: true, b: true, c: [1,2])`

Answer (score 4):

I think Rob is right about arel not supporting OR yet. From the [arel site](https://github.com/nkallen/arel):

The OR operator is not yet supported. It will work like this:

```
users.where(users[:name].eq('bob').or(users[:age].lt(25)))
```

The AND operator will behave similarly.

Answer (score 0):

There is frequently used method missing in ActiveRecords:

```rb
Route.where(:a => true, :b => true)
     .where_one_of(:c => 0..1, :d=1)
```

you can add it with following patch:

```rb
module ActiveRecordSearch

  def where_one_of fields
    relation = nil
    fields.each do |key, value|
      next unless value.present?

      where = self.where(key => value)
      relation = relation ? relation.or(where) : where
    end
    relation
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Relation.class_eval do
  include ActiveRecordSearch
end

ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  extend ActiveRecordSearch
end
```