# OR condition in where method ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I achieve something like this in Rails (if there is a way) with hash parameters without writing a where string:

```
Model.where(**:launched => nil or false**, :verify => false, :pools => {:status => 'later'})
```

Comment: Rials => rails Please do it on your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548548/rails3-combine-scope-with-or

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Model.where(:launched => [nil, false], :verify => false, :pools => {:status => 'later'})
```

Now you will query for all objects where :launched is nil or false.

P.s. Ditch the hash rockets and use the cleaner Ruby 1.9+ syntax, unless of course you want to stick with ruby 1.8.7 or earlier. For example: Model.where(launched: [nil, false])