# Combine multiple scope or where queries with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

How do I get the arel components in such a ways that I can do something like:

```
queries = []
queries << MyModel.some_scope.get_the_arel_component
queries << MyModel.some_scope_with_param("Dave").get_the_arel_component
queries << MyModel.where(:something => 'blah').get_the_arel_component
queries << MyModel.some_scope_with_join_and_merge.get_arel_component
# etc ... (may be any number of queries) 

# join each query with OR
combined_query = nil
queries.each do |query|
  combined_query ||= query
  combined_query = combined_query.or(q)
end

# run the query so it just works
MyModel.where(combined_query)
```

I've encountered some issues with accepted answers of similar questions.

Lets say I have a class like so:

```
class Patient
  has_one :account

  scope :older_than, ->(date) { where(arel_table[:dob].lt(date)) }
  scope :with_gender, ->(gender) { where(:gender => gender) }
  scope :with_name_like, ->(name) { where("lower(name) LIKE ?", name.downcase) }
  scope :in_arrears, -> { joins(:account).merge( Account.in_arrears ) } 
end
```

The goal is to combine any scope or where clause with an OR.

[One way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21681132/848668) would be `Patient.with_name_like("Susan") | Patient.with_name_like("Dave")`.  This seems to run each individual query separately instead of combine into a single query.  I've ruled this solution out.

[Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420230/848668) [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6714127/848668) that only works in some instances is:

```
# this fails because `where_values` for the `with_name_like` scope returns a string
sues = Patient.with_name_like("Susan").where_values.reduce(:and)
daves = Patient.with_name_like("Dave").where_values.reduce(:and)
Patient.where(sues.or(daves))

# this works as `where_values` returns an `Arel::Nodes::Equality` object
ages = Patient.older_than(7.years.ago).where_values.reduce(:and)
males = Patients.with_gender('M').where_values.reduce(:and)
Patient.where(ages.or(males))

# this fails as `in_arrears` scope requires a joins
of_age = Patient.older_than(18.years.ago).where_values.reduce(:and)
arrears = Patients.in_arrears.where_values.reduce(:and)
Patient.where(of_age.or(arrears)) # doesn't work as no join on accounts
Patient.join(:account).where(of_age.or(arrears)) # does work as we have our join
```

To sum up, the issues with ORing queries arise when `where` is passed a string or the query requires a join.

I'm pretty sure `where` converts anything passed to it into an arel object, it's just a matter of getting access to the correct pieces and recombining them in the correct way.  I just haven't managed to work it out yet.

<strike>Preferably the answer will only make use of ActiveRecord and AREL and not a third party library.</strike>

Comment: You seem to have it figured out pretty good. Or-ing is hard. I have no answers, just some ideas. Since you always need to go `where_values` you loose the needed join, and a `like` operator. So one solution is to work with the arel operators directly, but that means: no or-ing of existing scopes. Also: how you do a like. But imho you clearly documented the limitations of or-ing with arel. Personally I just avoid 'OR', or if it is really needed for performance reasons I write a custom query.

Comment: @nathanvda, thanks for the comments and suggestions.  I wouldn't mind working with the arel operators directly but I haven't been able to experiment with them and don't yet know how they all fit together.  Just for a bit more background, I'm trying to do an advanced search of a model where a user can choose to find records matching all (AND) or any (OR) of the options available.

Comment: Actually, Dan Shultz of this [amazing website](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/#/) suggested using the in operator.  I guess it would be something like `MyModel.where(:id => MyModel.select(:id).some_scope)`.  So in my first example the loop would become `queries.each {|q| combined_query.where(:id => q)}`.  I haven't yet tried it out but it seems seems like it could work.

Comment: Hmm actually thinking on my last comment a bit, that would still equate to ANDing each scope.  Plus it would do a new select for attributes even on the same table.  Maybe I need to think more about how to correctly apply his suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're open to using a third party library, how about [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)?

It has a very robust implementation allowing for all kinds of and and or condition combinations and works well with associated models as well.

For a use case like yours where there are a few predefined queries/scopes that I want the user to be able to select from and run the `or` combination of them, I use ransack's out of the box implementation and then on the view level, I use javascript to insert hidden fields with values that will result in the structured params hash ransack is expecting in the controller.

All of your scopes are simple to define in a view using ransack helpers. Your code should look like:

**Controller**

```
def index
  @q = Patient.search(params[:q])
  @patients = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

**View**

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :older_than %>
  <%= f.date_field :dob_lt %>
  <%= f.label :with_gender %>
  <%= f.text_field :gender_eq %>
  <%= f.label :with_name_like %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
  <%= f.label :in_arrears_exceeding %>
  <%= f.text_field :accounts_total_due_gte %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Also, if you want more control over the `anding` and `oring` take a look at the [complex search form builder](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo) example using ransack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Ransack, looks very promising ([complex search demo](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/)), however, it doesn't support scopes at present ([#61](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/61) and [#156](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/156)).  Though it looks like a solution is slowly being developed. A possible workaround to this is suggested by [charlie](https://github.com/charly), [here](https://coderwall.com/p/4zz6ca).

Comment: @br3nt yea, it doens't support scopes, but honestly, I find little use for them when using ransack. Also, using ransack gives us great flexibility on interface, we have a txtbox for `amount` for example, we allow users to enter '< 5000' or '>4000' or '500 - 1000' all of which get placed into hidden fields for the ransack search form. Also the complex grouping it allows means that you can create your own, then staticize the resulting form query and have like saved searches.

Comment: yeah it's the flexibility of it which is why I marked it as the correct answer, as I think it will be helpful to the most people.  I haven't had a chance to play with it too much, but I don't think it will suit my particular needs unfortunately, though I haven't yet had a decent look to see how much control there is to create customised criteria.  I'm still investigating a few other promising leads, and will post an answer my self hopefully within the week.

Comment: just for your interest here's a link to a gist showing an example of my usecase: https://gist.github.com/br3nt/d249e1935d3e7432fa4a

Answer (score 1):

I had worked on a similar problem in one of my previous projects. The requirement was to find a set of volunteers to scribe matching a set of criteria like email, location, stream of study etc. The solution that worked for me is to define fine-grained scopes and writing up my own query builder like this:

```
class MatchMaker
  # Scopes
  #   Volunteer => [ * - 'q' is mandatory, # - 'q' is optional, ** - 's', 'e' are mandatory ]
  #     active  - activation_state is 'active'
  #     scribes - type is 'scribe'
  #     readers - type is 'reader'
  #     located - located near (Geocoder)
  #     *by_name  - name like 'q'
  #     *by_email - email like 'q'
  #     educated - has education and title is not null
  #     any_stream - has education stream and is not null
  #     *streams - has education stream in 'q'
  #     #stream - has education stream like 'q'
  #     #education - has education and title like 'q'
  #     *level - education level (title) is 'q'
  #     *level_lt - education level (title) is < 'q'
  #     *level_lteq - education level (title) is <= 'q'
  #     *marks_lt - has education and marks obtained < 'q'
  #     *marks_lteq - has education and marks obtained <= 'q'
  #     *marks_gt - has education and marks obtained > 'q'
  #     *marks_gteq - has education and marks obtained >= 'q'
  #     *knows - knows language 'q'
  #     *reads - knows and reads language 'q'
  #     *writes - knows and writes language 'q'
  #     *not_engaged_on - doesn't have any volunteering engagements on 'q'
  #     **not_engaged_between - doesn't have any volunteering engagements betwee 'q' & 'q'
  #     #skyped - has skype id and is not null
  def search(scope, criteria)
    scope = scope.constantize.scoped

    criteria, singular = singular(criteria)
    singular.each do |k|
        scope = scope.send(k.to_sym)
    end

    if criteria.has_key?(:not_engaged_between)
      multi = criteria.select { |k, v| k.eql?(:not_engaged_between) }
      criteria.delete(:not_engaged_between)

      attrs = multi.values.flatten
      scope = scope.send(:not_engaged_between, attrs[0], attrs[1])
    end

    build(criteria).each do |k, v|
        scope = scope.send(k.to_sym, v)
    end

    scope.includes(:account).limit(Configuration.service_requests['limit']).all
  end

  def build(params)
    rejects = ['utf8', 'authenticity_token', 'action']
    required = ['by_name', 'by_email', 'by_mobile', 'streams', 'marks_lt', 'marks_lteq', 'marks_gt', 
      'marks_gteq', 'knows', 'reads', 'writes', 'not_engaged_on', 'located', 'excluding', 
      'level', 'level_lt', 'level_lteq']
    optional = ['stream', 'education']

    params.delete_if { |k, v| rejects.include?(k) }
    params.delete_if { |k, v| required.include?(k) && v.blank? }
    params.each { |k, v| params.delete(k) if optional.include?(k.to_s) && v.blank? }

    params
  end

  def singular(params)
    pattrs   = params.dup
    singular = ['active', 'scribes', 'readers', 'educated', 'any_stream', 'skyped']
    original = []

    pattrs.each { |k, v| original << k && pattrs.delete(k) if singular.include?(k.to_s) }

    [pattrs, original]
  end
end
```

The form would be something like this:

```
...

<%= f.input :paper ... %>

<%= f.input :writes ... %>

<%= f.input :exam_date ... %>

<%= f.time_select :start_time, { :combined => true, ... } %>

<%= f.time_select :end_time, { :combined => true, ... } %>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Education criteria</legend>

  <%= f.input :streams, :as => :check_boxes, 
    :collection => ..., 
    :input_html => { :title => 'The stream(s) from which the scribe can be taken' } %>

  <%= f.input :education, :as => :select, 
    :collection => ...,
    :input_html => { :class => 'input-large', :title => configatron.scribe_request.labels[:education]}, :label => configatron.scribe_request.labels[:education] %>

  <%= f.input :marks_lteq, :label => configatron.scribe_request.labels[:marks_lteq], 
    :wrapper => :append do %>
    <%= f.input_field :marks_lteq, :title => "Marks", :class => 'input-mini' %>
    <%= content_tag :span, "%", :class => "add-on" ... %>
  <% end %> 
</fieldset>

...
```

And finally

```
# Start building search criteria
criteria = service_request.attributes
...
# do cleanup of criteria
MatchMaker.new.search('<Klass>', criteria)
```

This has worked for me very well in the past. Hope this would lead you in the right direction in solving the problems you are facing. All the best.

Comment: this allows searching on one or more criteria, either optional or mandatory, where the record needs to match all criteria provided.  What I'm looking for is also the ability to match on any of the criteria.  That is at least one scope but not necessarily all scopes.  Eg any record that matches education level > 5 OR marks >= 95.  I don't think this will do it, but let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is the line that needs to be ORed somehow: `scope = scope.send(k.to_sym, v)`

Comment: Indeed, imho this does an AND of all the selected scopes.